# how to mark an interface as DataContract in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontract

i have two data classes which hold only data members(no functions). One is **CallTask** the other is **SmsTask**. These two classes have some common properties like **ID**, **Tel**. I put these common properties in a seperate interface class and i use this interface class in my project whenever appropriate. 
Now i added a WCFService to my project to share data between clients and server. Consider the following class design:

```
public interface IGsmTask : IComparable
{
    string TaskID { get; set; }
    string SessionID { get; set; }
    string Tel { get; set; }
}

class CallTask : IGsmTask
{
    #region IGsmTask Members

    public string TaskID { get; set; }

    public string SessionID { get; set; }

    public string Tel { get; set; }

    #endregion        
}

class SmsTask : IGsmTask
{
    #region IGsmTask Members

    public string TaskID { get; set; }

    public string SessionID { get; set; }

    public string Tel { get; set; }

    #endregion

    public string SmsText { get; set; }
}
```

in this design, i want to host CallTask, SmsTask, and IGsmTask to the clients to use these in service methots like the following;

```
    [OperationContract]
    public void AddTask(IGsmTask task)
    {

    }
```

i tried to mark **[DataContract]** on **IGsmTask**  but it gives me complition error. Isnt there any methot that i can use interfaces as DataContracts? Or how should i use KnownAttributes types in this synerio?
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Reniuz it seems that i can not use interfaces for this purpose.

Comment: WCF is a **message-based** system - the client sends an XML-serialized message to the server. As such, those messages must be **concrete types** that can be serialized into XML and represented with an XML schema. Interfaces cannot be serialized into XML ....

Comment: Well first thing that I would do is create class to store common properties, not interface. In this way you save at least 3 lines in each derived class.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As far as I know using interfaces as datacontracts is not possible. You may use a base class and add knowntype attributes on the otherhand.

Comment: i thought there would be a methot using interfaces as datacontracts. if it is not possible i will have to change my interface to a base class. Thanks.

Comment: Since serialization is based on object instances, I think there is no direct way to do it.

Answer (score 10):

Fer: Everything is Possible with the right design.

If the issue is:

a class is a data contract

&&

1 or more of its properties must be an interface...

```
public interface ICustomInterface
{
    int Property1 {get;set}
}

[DataContract]
public class MyClass
{
     [DataMember(Name="_myInterface")]
     public ICustomInterface MyInterface {get;set;}
}
```

The issue is that when the de-serialization occurs -- 
There is no way to turn the data into a class that implements ICustomInterface.

The Solution is to create a concrete class that does Implement the interface, and cast the getter/setter of the public property (that is of type interface) into a private property of the concrete class.

```
public class CustomInterfaceImplementor: ICustomInterface
{
     public int Property1 {get;set;}
}

[DataContract]
public class MyClass
{
     [DataMember(Name="_myInterface")]
     private CustomInterfaceImplementor _MyInterface;
     public ICustomInterface MyInterface
     {
          get {return (_MyInterface as ICustomInterface);}
          set {_MyInterface = (value as CustomInterfaceImplementor);}
     }
}
```

Comment: creating a new class means that everything has to again be initialized. which is a hassle if you just want to leave out a few properties. i consider this yet another language limitation

Comment: It seems to work just using: get { return _MyInterface; } set { _MyInterface = value; }    So you can leave the as out.