# ServiceRemoting V2_1 still throwing serialization exception when working with interface return types

Tags: c#, serialization, azure-service-fabric

over the last few days, I tried to equip my application with the service remoting IPC stack. I initially implemented the V2 version, but just noticed thanks to this post (https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/735) that that does not support returning interfaces.

So, I just now made the switch to V2_1.

However, I still face this problem:

```
One or more errors occurred. (Type 'MooMed.Core.DataTypes.Session.SessionContext' with data contract name 'SessionContext:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MooMed.Core.DataTypes.Session' is not expected. Add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.)'
```

This is the service method that is being called on the endpoint:

```
    [CanBeNull]
    public Task<ISessionContext> GetSessionContext(int accountId):
```

The involved classes/intefaces look like this:

```
public interface ISessionContext
{
    Account Account { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class SessionContext : ISessionContext
{
    [DataMember]
    public Account Account { get; set; }
}
```

Also, as I mentioned, I changed my remoting version from V2 to V2_1 just now, so this is added to the Service class which contains the `GetSessionContext` method:

```
[assembly: FabricTransportServiceRemotingProvider(RemotingListenerVersion = RemotingListenerVersion.V2_1, RemotingClientVersion = RemotingClientVersion.V2_1)]
```

So, according to the docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-remoting#use-the-remoting-v2-interface-compatible-stack) I should now be fully equipped to have everything working properly.

The only thing I see myself doing differently than the tutorial is how I declare the endpoint listeners. I'm doing this via `FabricTransportServiceRemotingListener` like this:

```
    public static ServiceReplicaListener CreateTypedListener([NotNull] IService service)
    {
        return new ServiceReplicaListener(context => new FabricTransportServiceRemotingListener(context, service), 
            $"I{service.GetType().Name}");
    }
```

However, I don't see how this could be the culprit, as the request comes in properly and I don't think declaring endpoints does necessarily interfere with how responses are serialized.

So, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: First when changing versions make sure all the code gets recompiled.  The dependencies in the compile to not recognize library version changes.   So I normally delete the bin folder of the project just to make sure everything compiles.  The error messages with serialization are not very good.  So I normally comment out all the suspicious code and get the serialization to run with no exceptions.  Then start un-commenting the code to find which part of code is actually failing.  You could have more than one problem so make sure you are chasing the right issue.

Comment: @jdweng The problem is certainly the point of using interfaces. If I return a concrete implementation it all works. I did as the manual told me to.

Comment: I think you should ask question at GITHUB.

Answer (score 0):

The DataContractSerializer can't serialize an interface.  (see [how to mark an interface as DataContract in WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972762/how-to-mark-an-interface-as-datacontract-in-wcf)).

However, you can write your own custom serializer to achieve this.  From that article you posted at the bottom are instructions on how to do this.  You can also look at my example of implementing protobuf-net here:
https://github.com/mikeruhl/Frenetik.Fabric.Remoting.Protobuf

My example should not be used in production.  It's a work in progress and there are zero tests written for it at the moment.